# perl execute system command without interpolation

Tags: powershell, perl, svn

I want to call svn commit in my perl script. following codes seem to work in git bash, but not powershell:

```perl
$task_number = $ARGV[0];
$comment     = $ARGV[1];
print(`svn commit -m '#$task_number $comment' 2>&1`);
```

when running in powershell, I get an error like

`svn: E200009: '$MY_WORKING_DIRECTORY\$comment' is not under version control`

where $comment is just what I get in my perl script. It seems that powershell has done some interpolation. How should I change my script to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried and the same problem. Only in git bash does the script work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backticks use `cmd`, not Power Shell.

On a build of Perl that uses `sh` (including macOS, MSYS and Cygwin), you should use

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote('svn', 'commit', '-m', "#$task_number $comment") . ' 2>&1';
`$cmd`
```

On a build of Perl that uses `cmd`, you should use

```
use Win32::ShellQuote qw( quote_system_cmd );

my $cmd = quote_system_cmd('svn', 'commit', '-m', "#$task_number $comment") . ' 2>&1';
`$cmd`
```